# lat-lon A to B route (straight line). Find if point is within distance form the route

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, gps, coords

Trying to solve it for couple days and still no solution :(
There is route on the map A to B it is a straight line. A and B is lat-Lon coords. I need to find if point C (lat-lon) is within certain distance from the route. I need this solution to be 'very fast' since it might be many such points. Here is a picture:

http://www.framesbyleon.com/images/map.png

A -> B is a route, I need to calculate that rectangle (or stripe) around the route and use its coords to filter results with MySql. In human language it is like driving on a highway and pick up something if it isnt that far off.
It seems I need to convert coords to Cartesian and do calculations?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120357/get-closest-point-to-a-line). If you can show what you have tried, that is very useful here. You need to imagine A-B forms a line, and then create an intersecting line from C to A-B so that it is perpendicular. There is sure to be a solution to that if you search for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to draw a polygon around a polyline in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369363/how-to-draw-a-polygon-around-a-polyline-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number))`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge) method in the geometry library