# polygon around closed loop polyline issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to draw a polygon on map around google maps direction polyline. I use solution based on JSTS library, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369363/how-to-draw-a-polygon-around-a-polyline-in-javascript)
Everything is ok, until direction polyline creates closed loops. In such cases i receive strange artifacts (as you can see on image below)[polygon bug inside closed loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnnN2.png)

For drawing polygon i use this function

```
        function drawPoligon(){
            var overviewPath = mainPath;
            var overviewPathGeo = [];
            var polygonalPath = [];
            var lDistance = 0.00899928005759539 * 5 *2;
            for (var i = 0; i < overviewPath.length; i++) {
                overviewPathGeo.push([overviewPath[i].lat(), overviewPath[i].lng() ]);
            }
            var geoInput = googleMaps2JTS(overviewPath);
            var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();
            var shell = geometryFactory.createLineString(geoInput);
            var polygon = shell.buffer(lDistance);
            if (routePolygon && routePolygon.setMap) routePolygon.setMap(null);
            routePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: jsts2googleMaps(polygon),
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                map: map
            });
        }
```

Full example is [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z2nhaef/3/)

Is it possible to avoid this issue with JSTS library or is it something wrong from Google side when drawing polygon?

Comment: Looks to me like the issue is that it is a complex self intersecting polygon with a single path.  The google maps API expects polygons with holes to have an external path and separate paths for the holes (which "wind" the opposite direction).  The function `jsts2googleMaps` needs to be modified to address the holes in the polygons (currently it just process the outer boundary, and it seems like there might be an issue with how it does that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

```
var polygon = shell.buffer(lDistance);

var wktWriter = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();
var wkt = wktWriter.write(polygon);
console.log(wkt);
```

you can extract the WKT for the generated buffer polygon:

```
POLYGON ((43.53564851585564 -1.619308730713745, 43.48029565895185 -1.6815942016692849, 43.37754344989339 -1.9635971597872128, 43.36806254752958 -2.2471770416347034, 43.365070840360964 -2.2673703343947054, 43.35760507166823 -2.286369852338605, 43.26040507166823 -2.4694498523386055, 43.25088257303102 -2.483853379142792, 43.238784525186446 -2.4961731519915507, 42.994869049951106 -2.7009527181067208, 42.78135258237344 -2.978642772583373, 42.38549606185889 -3.7836035068779834, 42.38541430255075 -3.7837693312814222, 42.14935430255075 -4.2613093312814225, 42.141395750868526 -4.274450031413887, 41.858166438751326 -4.662892503991992, 41.56089359834704 -5.079132430427735, 41.55441856165125 -5.087178973493849, 41.24409635897653 -5.430460104880776, 41.030435825626135 -5.757301488089262, 41.01901732161862 -5.77142054291938, 41.00499690042606 -5.782959942065295, 40.988945388268654 -5.7914498714246125, 40.971516305029105 -5.796544672745033, 40.95341925690045 -5.7980369167246515, 40.93539104554065 -5.795865848270679, 40.62624795235644 -5.726440192736536, 40.483984159596915 -5.77833191172212, 40.3873120383163 -5.9284533015437795, 40.37930822727815 -5.939068591465263, 40.36982784933882 -5.948388881448894, 40.016853932461885 -6.247480024841379, 39.87266046124207 -6.424412284059634, 39.861881372594304 -6.435529859808562, 39.849355943002244 -6.444634960365061, 39.83545502973115 -6.451457998752695, 39.8205902158443 -6.455796956083524, 39.6269102158443 -6.494626956083525, 39.62329588809884 -6.495275170471416, 39.48765588809884 -6.5167551704714155, 39.469156760090264 -6.517754031419404, 39.45084508482626 -6.514943691707348, 39.43349689387108 -6.508443250887383, 39.4178473872307 -6.498528191523773, 39.32893751926425 -6.42839931989709, 39.03303224261663 -6.422755158401821, 38.801760450456236 -6.472407811866554, 38.783784531682855 -6.474408153594262, 38.765771671772086 -6.472773558656763, 37.88437167177209 -6.302203558656763, 37.875199514670946 -6.299923025717001, 37.58123951467095 -6.210203025717, 37.56549573882405 -6.203713327483473, 37.41009573882405 -6.121673327483474, 37.396746769570726 -6.1130379870886955, 37.38512571085102 -6.102188329117445, 37.375595260968815 -6.089462976120274, 37.36845286941565 -6.075259091906398, 37.32735286941565 -5.9715990919063975, 37.32265787140171 -5.955535716227444, 37.32101832841842 -5.938880778720506, 37.322490940286535 -5.922210252068958, 37.43852662170958 -5.2889470560903264, 37.449239375139584 -5.052437923722475, 37.45137531508278 -5.036608637310881, 37.456276052477016 -5.0214062914151345, 37.463787202374995 -5.007309796285093, 37.47367214559314 -4.99476322522702, 37.64973214559314 -4.8080932252270205, 37.664262120619014 -4.795650805371191, 37.79885211831474 -4.703242077889873, 37.85544827777655 -4.534401441751917, 37.91920378074939 -4.20363722421752, 37.920032497455196 -4.199792025871217, 38.0274924974552 -3.749232025871217, 38.032684002883855 -3.733807921348083, 38.04056849799679 -3.7195710162851694, 38.05088813341761 -3.7069869051231694, 38.252258133417605 -3.5023669051231696, 38.26359625170664 -3.4926170398455345, 38.27639233089176 -3.484879265181189, 38.29029305925405 -3.479367228328446, 38.60754305925405 -3.3831972283284455, 38.611996222371566 -3.3819711701857336, 38.95228265576371 -3.297614152761289, 39.05211417437582 -3.03910456659342, 39.15874092147138 -2.604649936413835, 39.16427923332939 -2.5887165941144694, 39.172693686073465 -2.574096700815166, 39.338608263811786 -2.33976898790898, 39.444250736025225 -1.8930987631084446, 39.43612988897129 -1.4095712163193452, 39.436127259359544 -1.406714436053196, 39.43956223136781 -1.177005401368284, 39.36822006687206 -0.9357052052238741, 39.36477541210122 -0.9168693037347543, 39.365393810579675 -0.8977310066652667, 39.42237381057968 -0.4901210066652667, 39.42622386751201 -0.4738278629769483, 39.433025261039454 -0.4585298070313348, 39.442542600542986 -0.4447562919242586, 39.714322600542985 -0.1206462919242586, 39.72696600563561 -0.1082742864967476, 39.741785301990326 -0.0986145418735264, 39.75820789343787 -0.0920402966102499, 39.89427686520032 -0.0525684989986741, 39.98223718234058 0.0912535794603264, 39.998064139025225 0.1105140935567843, 40.323464139025226 0.4100240935567844, 40.331893409460136 0.4168901742853132, 40.693821288096046 0.6769773784164531, 41.00065397476793 1.0932433402325612, 41.130321914609375 1.5388065093925318, 41.135654431293176 1.5527170904493335, 41.14320877400426 1.5655573359969996, 41.30865945896108 1.7999458063524947, 41.38607897349551 2.041503701452226, 41.40852277872286 2.1329176296113435, 41.41521889974535 2.151285074679046, 41.52966710214742 2.383201673215253, 41.56533696673627 2.4656460905199076, 41.661499085095826 2.715818549839911, 41.66857390952571 2.730232042351961, 41.678097482848 2.743158892636684, 41.68976664602418 2.7541876068807087, 41.69800016550522 2.759564729281136, 41.70644782000306 2.779975390703296, 41.71381958586507 2.794098984219297, 41.72356636078527 2.806701333380636, 41.73538267429366 2.8173874721033387, 41.74889819519137 2.8258224896251276, 41.76368933797911 2.831742026833573, 41.93483505073441 2.88319705617618, 41.991807799294904 2.9078397699146312, 42.116664080583575 3.0001915758260886, 42.131485250996626 3.0090891264880364, 42.14773421616076 3.0149886714950105, 42.16481140668298 3.0176725239615356, 42.18208669254259 3.017041652609129, 42.22961113447575 3.0106980602898723, 42.262693709667964 3.025007435399743, 42.281024624717055 3.0307055552350683, 42.300147029292376 3.0323862275566538, 42.319190854039775 3.0299729817786143, 42.33728960498704 3.023575620577034, 42.482679953471234 2.9539492766356994, 42.60728390669895 2.945873456769405, 42.725674939960484 2.9844744417479494, 42.814367213990614 3.0345319643581252, 42.83017728861574 3.041546495613007, 42.84703728408007 3.0454068921366924, 42.86432440052658 3.045970552799294, 42.9061164917346 3.043306782658022, 42.940323504839505 3.054459860409328, 42.95562513400342 3.0580070900996743, 43.05584356574839 3.072172491717032, 43.14634989771064 3.1502039557156083, 43.22602608425816 3.284358196132736, 43.40617005677547 3.7474272398314303, 43.4103743477056 3.7566579502605038, 43.56354987189491 4.048187467930003, 43.67728829430034 4.288653078701769, 43.57165293862556 4.622371789178716, 43.568637123887015 4.635004946057162, 43.56314243353226 4.668602016035432, 43.55647682639173 4.686533242232076, 43.55241697777116 4.7011018596662675, 43.550854126645504 4.7161446147704655, 43.55024681934295 4.747451746294855, 43.49080776168142 5.110889547293133, 43.46666832713945 5.154086556024212, 43.24997759167187 5.285988843651493, 43.23619697834737 5.296304660594558, 43.22463265557899 5.309055653564159, 43.2157077473688 5.323775279790453, 43.20974880486516 5.339924966692696, 43.206973858267574 5.356913817571512, 43.20748443937634 5.3741202317747545, 43.21126186667188 5.390914648282303, 43.21816792884803 5.406682580550717, 43.227949941789596 5.420847099801763, 43.24024999396581 5.432889944119632, 43.25461804196241 5.442370481001566, 43.27052837700316 5.44894182954605, 43.287398859971795 5.452363552388021, 43.30461222114887 5.452510452999166, 43.32153864533326 5.44937715647118, 43.33755881598692 5.443078306176887, 43.60370881598692 5.3077483061768875, 43.61795801724444 5.298730567506901, 43.630274739631986 5.287212855198217, 43.64022652197176 5.273599575818904, 43.64746394017378 5.2583687148791345, 43.651732876112995 5.242055053942839, 43.66333495093081 5.171114619745263, 43.71317868317388 5.08192031268101, 43.721483304468364 5.061545953590456, 43.7245958733545 5.039765385229535, 43.729949048729665 4.76380531552713, 43.73794452134593 4.714917309897164, 43.8098279044852 4.521542996698896, 43.936361940999355 4.7665366458244876, 43.947084771029864 4.782730757735101, 43.96103249856244 4.7962470161342905, 44.041482498562445 4.8588870161342905, 44.05802482333588 4.869105091201972, 44.07637582106998 4.875531478146541, 44.09567884440215 4.877866185245096, 44.115032804232634 4.876000225471024, 44.335854999203576 4.8302351074698215, 44.791862879222535 4.943298000979607, 44.810201507759864 4.945881594919447, 45.20532150775986 4.9604615949194475, 45.21760432553438 4.960075212173612, 45.54951555614853 4.926847748108046, 45.67934964928413 4.931322403836236, 45.728834276387126 4.976803962305678, 45.81931103022975 5.260889674821248, 45.82750073615335 5.27922279512768, 45.839551544208945 5.295283698230934, 45.85486353378916 5.308272830549168, 45.977103533789155 5.390422830549167, 45.99151875552967 5.398303644098207, 46.00712646024775 5.403432522480073, 46.02340648933878 5.405638535358076, 46.03981627761666 5.40484816285206, 46.0558089354056 5.40108774573841, 46.13307548497351 5.3752812175599916, 46.50293825151767 5.415449583316469, 46.65267188904149 5.557415831981785, 46.668007943934434 5.569108806537554, 46.68548320638981 5.577265732168993, 46.88375320638981 5.645035732168993, 46.90134891714281 5.649133566466324, 46.91940855794427 5.649634222988971, 46.9372042728543 5.646517523825989, 46.95401884291243 5.639909080999431, 46.96917459214336 5.630075233935295, 47.04524474330286 5.569047450470973, 47.06244992403565 5.615898608115111, 47.10600735322924 5.816963505754076, 47.107246572671805 5.821982508728847, 47.375556572671805 6.788482508728847, 47.38374474350355 6.808370075610367, 47.39641792285521 6.825746841223028, 47.60039323509102 7.04473754451253, 47.686657391893284 7.383686061423757, 47.69216033732215 7.399202533468003, 47.70039790019829 7.413456861616135, 47.71109438995554 7.425971989260948, 47.72389182191307 7.43632906647343, 47.73836189812466 7.444181467859229, 47.75402034143661 7.449266393241123, 47.7703431030293 7.451413662921734, 48.0121344972951 7.460896965850807, 48.30605537748006 7.582027882335158, 48.44972195006908 7.670830522265899, 48.48721618966563 7.781246321186368, 48.49449874535519 7.797314707586964, 48.5047761554564 7.811653588313924, 48.5176534648627 7.823711928222248, 48.532635805795294 7.833026332071654, 48.549147415294335 7.839238852545786, 48.566553761466594 7.8421107459668455, 48.58418592819026 7.841531647081238, 48.60136632118637 7.837523810334376, 48.617434707586966 7.830241254644817, 48.631773588313926 7.819963844543611, 48.643831928222255 7.807086535137305, 48.65314633207166 7.7921041942047085, 48.65935885254579 7.775592584705667, 48.66223074596685 7.758186238533409, 48.66165164708124 7.740554071809745, 48.65764381033438 7.723373678813633, 48.609753810334375 7.582343678813633, 48.60352441695074 7.568150357821391, 48.594951876289 7.555236518372196, 48.584290500859055 7.543985261702003, 48.571856570425744 7.534730366959411, 48.39444657042575 7.425070366959411, 48.3814200748777 7.418416064273465, 48.0659300748777 7.288396064273465, 48.05084467451795 7.283680237533515, 48.03516689697071 7.281676337078268, 47.844515557166226 7.274198798786677, 47.76914260810672 6.978043938576245, 47.76424341505359 6.963864103341382, 47.757056662763524 6.950695184958276, 47.7477820771448 6.938903158776974, 47.543103684247754 6.719157618410448, 47.28136514719164 5.776329188367839, 47.23703264677077 5.571686494245925, 47.2335566998627 5.559717567216439, 47.1710466998627 5.38949756721644, 47.1636909537456 5.374140450100579, 47.153574139994 5.36044380355608, 47.14105845857635 5.348897991947469, 47.126591993200236 5.3399163759140835, 47.11069266911677 5.333820513322246, 47.0939297104733 5.3308286469203825, 47.076903261074065 5.331047890859548, 47.06022289816214 5.334470395815853, 47.044485808467336 5.340973630010258, 47.03025540785664 5.350324766064707, 46.89514300596892 5.458719586898699, 46.76226679697281 5.413301618049825, 46.60474811095851 5.263954168018216, 46.589245941374756 5.252160943314468, 46.57156933898849 5.24397955353067, 46.55254639395424 5.239793269624797, 46.13294639395424 5.194223269624796, 46.11361174432464 5.1942126659244545, 46.09472106459441 5.19833225426159, 46.040766019107195 5.216352890740381, 45.98129030836324 5.176382916610671, 45.89307896977026 4.899410325178753, 45.88709517575667 4.88505201598336, 45.87872821936913 4.871938630663142, 45.86822808207459 4.860461960826323, 45.77662808207459 4.776271960826323, 45.76399453395176 4.766574493827484, 45.74984936452202 4.759255915675303, 45.73463559348845 4.754545440613975, 45.71882970862725 4.752590598390197, 45.54966970862725 4.746760598390197, 45.537605674465624 4.747154787826389, 45.20580386195415 4.7803712981014845, 44.826141436014545 4.76636168540104, 44.35929712077747 4.650611999020393, 44.33938052545742 4.647984032505144, 44.31937719576737 4.649839774528976, 44.11923730240239 4.6913185119258305, 44.087206126169555 4.666378389126272, 43.82908805900065 4.166613354175514, 43.8287956522944 4.166052049739497, 43.80051979508469 4.112236356549174, 43.63198390203556 3.765444399336609, 43.24324084434293 2.8584748701884175, 43.28016401376391 2.3743721361862384, 43.4542441216353 1.7931512288040699, 43.62241286067716 1.5623628649052812, 43.784504815151955 1.4697338306064203, 43.915415936417276 1.4126241390396161, 43.97532282822007 1.4580177734337114, 44.15587706112192 1.609729287250026, 44.17115019936396 1.6200906885489101, 44.18821590480146 1.6271184254931519, 44.206356402520456 1.630516915031763, 44.22480871238883 1.6301432184186655, 44.414573097922705 1.606689193240321, 44.71675823976191 1.646318767574328, 44.7353880646779 1.6468157269422898, 45.0184980646779 1.6249557269422898, 45.04240330395559 1.6197759136959693, 45.14739108158487 1.5814876048025888, 45.25963666422163 1.6516354629012713, 45.27514291098014 1.6593598444544675, 45.29184189911313 1.6639700021794783, 45.30911482230214 1.6652950996934885, 45.32632160619522 1.663286033499465, 45.342824627332284 1.6580172525906733, 45.63065462733229 1.5344772525906734, 45.648454171686836 1.5242950702938245, 45.88715417168683 1.3488650702938245, 45.90111766020975 1.3361422344340244, 45.91211760465652 1.3207848002012783, 45.9196693194151 1.303469455323101, 45.92344005666958 1.2849591580644724, 45.97070005666958 0.7932091580644723, 45.970673981687774 0.7757237102700673, 45.943183981687774 0.4983737102700673, 45.93847284573897 0.4772434060177355, 45.92885172282962 0.4578496298592021, 45.78698729815517 0.2418333044383618, 45.53708103902252 -0.1876038279874952, 45.52476202256167 -0.2040929574809136, 45.509018636424834 -0.2173517413979932, 45.201069317516776 -0.4214640568664098, 45.364787926528386 -0.4865680675820742, 45.60383699823419 -0.4998354842308098, 45.62867116579262 -0.5047818011834363, 45.79049164897908 -0.5616158351754783, 45.986977001015156 -0.4598240386556381, 46.226519928678144 -0.3105734158567424, 46.34847839487196 -0.035511224862304, 46.453386451032756 0.2762604296148006, 46.460637748630546 0.2923719532791147, 46.4708971651488 0.3067562114922648, 46.483769253962116 0.3188587666447731, 46.641089253962114 0.4400187666447731, 46.83645960551725 0.5903944357688612, 46.85637939269984 0.6020002073113744, 47.14048939269984 0.7218202073113743, 47.146412826781244 0.7240760875099508, 47.34266293187507 0.7910022749354305, 47.47801057583739 1.0648924452826323, 47.80193066930485 1.782792066427175, 47.80974306116457 1.7966774473367837, 47.88205306116457 1.9021174473367837, 47.89295078348443 1.915168267962137, 47.90610869325894 1.9259364470617615, 47.9210571172319 1.9340376131186086, 47.93726246951596 1.9391825939840421, 47.95414629800847 1.9411877389143162, 48.134740442194015 1.9454506908156917, 48.44262064190749 1.9927658212098944, 48.71416243893898 2.395518286959587, 48.726788853618224 2.4104465076148065, 48.74234139801089 2.422295409779029, 48.760085954990224 2.4305056970572383, 48.77918493921605 2.434689824340774, 48.84763493921605 2.442029824340774, 48.86527595336312 2.442182398104603, 48.88260776603466 2.4388904490757, 48.89896432538951 2.432280485009099, 48.91371705802452 2.4226065231169702, 48.92629902469795 2.4102403283296066, 48.9362267074866 2.395657126577645, 48.943118591108394 2.37941734212606, 48.94670982434077 2.3621450607839494, 48.94686239810461 2.344504046636884, 48.9435704490757 2.32717223396534, 48.9369604850091 2.310815674610493, 48.92728652311697 2.2960629419754857, 48.91492032832961 2.2834809753020533, 48.90033712657765 2.2735532925134074, 48.88409734212606 2.2666614088916077, 48.86682506078395 2.2630701756592266, 48.839996639678375 2.2601933223222663, 48.56983756106103 1.8594917130404138, 48.55795183023255 1.8452754183959423, 48.5434063583027 1.8337948749818271, 48.52681785276091 1.8255368416423665, 48.50888964283951 1.820851447340928, 48.15633964283951 1.766671447340928, 48.14479370199154 1.765652261085684, 48.00443819092792 1.7623391481635813, 47.962700121665485 1.7014781051123973, 47.64141933069515 0.9894279335728251, 47.64006934973702 0.9865708806027076, 47.48755934973702 0.6779508806027077, 47.478261597921716 0.663016974229099, 47.466236194284015 0.6501772150512561, 47.45194265661424 0.6399222392210773, 47.43592717321876 0.6326439124900493, 47.20750863699411 0.554747486602706, 46.9370299579998 0.440676333468009, 46.75090057138021 0.2974133973424801, 46.61525348391082 0.1929447912034571, 46.51773354896726 -0.0968704296148006, 46.514708774150726 -0.1046467454036252, 46.37984877415072 -0.4088067454036253, 46.37102710951653 -0.4243321755234368, 46.359313698279486 -0.4378101851878933, 46.34516971879468 -0.4487101205847912, 46.07912971879468 -0.6144701205847912, 46.07293654368403 -0.6179963847669289, 45.83875654368403 -0.7393163847669288, 45.82171545320867 -0.7460443814804726, 45.803664909141226 -0.7491816674470537, 45.78535304728487 -0.7485982124610643, 45.76753883420739 -0.7443181988165638, 45.58109447670724 -0.6788358523105409, 45.34017300176582 -0.6654645157691903, 45.32578755386616 -0.6634929476422725, 45.31190641600394 -0.6592335810457794, 45.10487289199128 -0.5769050488942132, 44.924351800143306 -0.5903609695585061, 44.848347793939745 -0.6498915493011986, 44.756168529147146 -0.7771594562051761, 44.6888734931849 -0.8949126751519924, 44.67839262438869 -0.9096049793059805, 44.66519091296755 -0.9219105564005212, 44.649799303278506 -0.931334502668235, 44.63283681266325 -0.9374978073178644, 44.614985635905924 -0.9401525955307654, 44.59696370883038 -0.9391920974514439, 44.55072171780816 -0.9320288442409472, 44.411772537505044 -0.9234851092905753, 44.40034943243251 -0.9295115318253887, 44.02772370319145 -1.132848928419387, 43.72915819035821 -1.4140770039576989, 43.683961714828754 -1.4693787732442753, 43.67813200200813 -1.4758462912433192, 43.53564851585564 -1.619308730713745),   (41.239962439381905 1.271430215560471, 41.16899808539063 1.0275834906074686, 41.163260270594435 1.0128425132688847, 41.15503005349201 0.9993339064577006, 40.830290053492014 0.5587739064577005, 40.82109876663305 0.5481520519314949, 40.81036659053987 0.5390898257146869, 40.44134897318362 0.2739078211256692, 40.129216169706915 -0.0133905684542563, 40.02962281765942 -0.1762335794603264, 40.019682466120585 -0.1895471189600541, 40.00746399305624 -0.2008063302424857, 39.99338389015243 -0.2096274200246319, 39.97792210656214 -0.2157097033897502, 39.834646062521614 -0.2572721767420733, 39.597050874091245 -0.5406152355476053, 39.546343166813784 -0.9033559965754325, 39.61604993312794 -1.139124794776126, 39.618908681561834 -1.1524156939804695, 39.61973274064046 -1.1659855639468042, 39.61611410049609 -1.4079771529419718, 39.62440011102872 -1.901338783680655, 39.621996716685615 -1.923562866775786, 39.509736716685616 -2.3982128667757863, 39.50417754011776 -2.4145381866259217, 39.495606313926544 -2.4295032991848347, 39.32946455182724 -2.664151873539377, 39.22553907852863 -3.0876000635861653, 39.222090266792 -3.0985700071106668, 39.103320266792004 -3.4061200071106668, 39.095598274697274 -3.4215325651850415, 39.085079141037355 -3.43518994177617, 39.07214885783564 -3.446590989299561, 39.057281892509074 -3.455317354538629, 39.04102377762844 -3.461048829814267, 38.65754609616332 -3.5561129589797096, 38.36445510794893 -3.6449594848633295, 38.19675265413714 -3.815368563171752, 38.095563888292475 -4.2396344326950395, 38.03104621925061 -4.574352775782481, 38.02800664500212 -4.585921884696384, 37.959936645002124 -4.788991884696383, 37.951859355976616 -4.806555367503164, 37.94021735895346 -4.821988527633827, 37.92554787938099 -4.83457919462881, 37.774067841920626 -4.938584527418704, 37.62752901985107 -5.093954298608782, 37.61805062486042 -5.303212076277526, 37.61666905971347 -5.315359747931042, 37.504181703795005 -5.929258004420012, 37.52351678447092 -5.978023806436211, 37.6419607597174 -6.040553688863629, 37.923214367266944 -6.126395550577283, 38.781936617013365 -6.292576914474771, 39.00543954954377 -6.2445921881334465, 39.02604623004194 -6.242603565807782, 39.36262623004194 -6.249023565807782, 39.38189323780701 -6.251487670087936, 39.400182712251826 -6.258028657983897, 39.41664261276931 -6.268341808476228, 39.4983959869527 -6.332825897973683, 39.59333033434529 -6.317792060005585, 39.75354292897135 -6.285671784038371, 39.88257953875794 -6.127337715940366, 39.89416215066119 -6.1155311185511065, 40.24324534427856 -5.81973676512719, 40.3490479616837 -5.655436698456222, 40.36126828358472 -5.64033325972771, 40.376445385184304 -5.628204545211055, 40.393871918881715 -5.619615828654809, 40.58937191888171 -5.548305828654809, 40.60591363069792 -5.544000025434546, 40.62297109713282 -5.542899566437251, 40.63992895445936 -5.545044151729322, 40.913934027489105 -5.6065787039615325, 41.09729417437387 -5.326088511910739, 41.10586143834876 -5.314981026506152, 41.417432668281805 -4.970318210255315, 41.71195640165296 -4.557927569572266, 41.712474249131475 -4.557209968586114, 41.991422101069766 -4.174639419947334, 42.22402473262521 -3.7040935389298593, 42.62379393814112 -2.891176493122017, 42.633208217455135 -2.8760351531874893, 42.858158217455134 -2.5834751531874893, 42.87163547481356 -2.56940684800845, 43.10964550430126 -2.3695852068332663, 43.18887305578543 -2.2203570162394266, 43.19813745247042 -1.9432529583652964, 43.19973087342743 -1.929138785400355, 43.2035251818358 -1.915451123345326, 43.247891389250924 -1.7936882741941245, 43.20958003654262 -1.7581086248916595, 43.11776098605806 -1.7357094503868586, 42.98203092628576 -1.7207189131183382, 42.96874856500834 -1.718231210229794, 42.82091799523554 -1.6788576996435762, 42.47790279785228 -1.7826461406357093, 42.45792750233613 -1.7862966720110007, 42.28904750233613 -1.7977466720110007, 42.27564238799828 -1.7976547975642718, 42.05991238799828 -1.7800547975642718, 42.04302529484697 -1.7770366197077287, 42.027017730158235 -1.77086886603149, 42.012471362193324 -1.76177565473382, 41.99991476358186 -1.7500874066193493, 41.98980420453256 -1.7362288385697486, 41.69315420453256 -1.2354888385697487, 41.683608539049594 -1.2127429136497752, 41.58821525919391 -0.853943281407895, 41.4312901580409 -0.3088986162312602, 41.42808884574463 -0.2914829624432692, 41.37902884574463 0.2964870375567308, 41.379474202627335 0.3156180308536826, 41.43220372514522 0.7195799576437255, 41.32513759779301 1.026542270352199, 41.239962439381905 1.271430215560471),   (43.06289118742524 2.8563941164486017, 43.056978568198595 2.8550281940094555, 43.03957559947343 2.8544494472007065, 42.92910350196817 2.861490786034732, 42.798520516216165 2.818914657314478, 42.73566278600939 2.783438035641875, 42.712687944328515 2.7743639940395823, 42.534117944328514 2.730953994039582, 42.5178322309215 2.728544665850231, 42.50138011800698 2.729142415084601, 42.48531218811615 2.7327272376077723, 42.470166166801725 2.7391791645945265, 42.327537504960546 2.816044856136075, 42.2552618162883 2.825692260395447, 42.08222633175769 2.7508483390537473, 42.06912591941643 2.741158424173912, 42.05592086458354 2.733050455183794, 42.04152066202089 2.7273279731664277, 41.9966804704962 2.7138467510342084, 41.98212218476456 2.707549781397464, 41.83993470773281 2.6318532136453516, 41.77271217999694 2.4694346092967048, 41.77026110025466 2.4640249253209543, 41.69306454318352 2.307594657663722, 41.5669194566765 2.0160331877004034, 41.55938363878972 1.9925205589073582, 41.50716722127715 1.7798423703886568, 41.50165608306295 1.7639720807422568, 41.493291225995755 1.7494026640030007, 41.47109698056493 1.7179608163093345, 41.4625344009437 1.6995594095261497, 41.381091046719135 1.5699110814379633, 41.38685741109804 1.3969766830548282, 41.495095350137966 1.0857806074791683, 41.609172402206994 0.7587177296478013, 41.61371677331787 0.7383239953624203, 41.61343579737267 0.7174319691463175, 41.559191282488285 0.3018636555312493, 41.60671137254421 -0.2676509663640138, 41.76142984195911 -0.8050313837687398, 41.76192146095041 -0.806807086350225, 41.85435218579662 -1.1544637570595515, 42.12093423530932 -1.6044495837003354, 42.28357848579274 -1.617718664535213, 42.435557598663294 -1.6074145382777054, 42.793287202147724 -1.4991738593642912, 42.80955009080785 -1.4958523791098322, 42.82614636737302 -1.4955742014242126, 42.842511434991664 -1.4983487897702064, 43.008523907052385 -1.5425649071549457, 43.14330907371425 -1.557451086881662, 43.154758200507324 -1.559471103068705, 43.27498820050732 -1.588801103068705, 43.28944933234788 -1.5936598610537895, 43.302881988787625 -1.6008914310243767, 43.313812039810266 -1.6094372409162305, 43.3199819551815 -1.5977044529542161, 43.32433885069094 -1.5885378745125107, 43.325981626675016 -1.5862954028716971, 43.33231908508401 -1.5742440129810842, 43.339415466775456 -1.5628895655157486, 43.34811799799188 -1.552713708756681, 43.404427814066075 -1.4960170079790909, 43.52901210404662 -1.355829281289791, 43.534575910175946 -1.3501019130603804, 43.59721477713324 -1.2911004301324436, 43.70918828517125 -1.1540912267557248, 43.72255224181992 -1.1408473061560362, 43.92420224181992 -0.979057306156036, 43.93852837457748 -0.9696547265858213, 44.31524613610733 -0.7709118810168628, 44.34797254180809 -0.7530534734704369, 44.354047353920215 -0.7504417433510472, 44.373148374577475 -0.7403647265858213, 44.390927314848604 -0.7332856091266702, 44.409801096593505 -0.7301257066264808, 44.42891629116963 -0.7310279025485561, 44.55337992312984 -0.7503083117939254, 44.604713080287965 -0.679434851466516, 44.69963650681511 -0.5133373248480078, 44.70905166538754 -0.4998823873869078, 44.72075509108586 -0.4883623882571316, 44.73435706893172 -0.4791609344748798, 45.05297598304053 -0.3036903658069058, 45.39207980696299 -0.0789284896305474, 45.63264896097749 0.3344638279874952, 45.635208277170385 0.338600370140798, 45.76625900687732 0.538150730563963, 45.790699595034425 0.7847348384349038, 45.74813071548133 1.2276727673437546, 45.550181760876264 1.373153224429502, 45.315098680111916 1.474053630216343, 45.20552333577837 1.405574537098729, 45.19095175560346 1.398214116609095, 45.17529022685253 1.3936072461136282, 45.15905412863667 1.3919055254247474, 45.14277774761453 1.3931649536284858, 45.12699669604442 1.397344086304031, 44.992334052272035 1.446454611525001, 44.73087271543445 1.4666430358945732, 44.4266117602381 1.426741232425672, 44.40387128761118 1.4266567815813347, 44.241644188962056 1.446707321863811, 44.089372938878086 1.3187607127499743, 44.08583016645203 1.3159329927981078, 43.98210016645203 1.2373329927981078, 43.96579427602463 1.2275042692555254, 43.94778558077877 1.2213258580804431, 43.92888012294321 1.2190742957040586, 43.90992408249723 1.2208503586863224, 43.89176590342197 1.22657455310804, 43.70808590342197 1.3067045531080401, 43.699419228643265 1.3110554188419001, 43.51637922864327 1.4156554188419002, 43.50100795441868 1.4267373475562857, 43.488297973747684 1.4407922970994484, 43.29971797374768 1.6995922970994484, 43.291826016755806 1.7126090360128263, 43.28624085678435 1.7267697021410098, 43.10496085678436 2.3320297021410097, 43.1014378212951 2.3510060055250173, 43.06289118742524 2.8563941164486017))
```

Importing it on JTS TestBuilder it looks like this which means that JSTS is generating a correct polygon but Google Maps is not drawing it correctly:

[image]