# Trying to create a 'lozenge' with google maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I am current using google maps API to plot points on a map.  I am looking for the best way to achieve a 'lozenge' type effect between points (see image).
Essentially the thickness of the lozenge will be determined dynamically.

The only way I can see to do this, is to draw 2 circles at the ends of my points, and create a rectangle in between them, with no borders.  I don't like this idea, as it essentially adds 3 polygons to my map for each line I have, and means that I would have to then add 3 click events for each line (one on each polygon) to display data that I want to show, when clicking on the line.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a polygon around a polyline in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369363/how-to-draw-a-polygon-around-a-polyline-in-javascript)

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lv0efa5c/3/) using code from that duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Just create 2 Polylines...

```js
function initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 20, lng: 0},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 20, lng: -20},
    {lat: 20, lng: 20}
  ];
  
  new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: .3,
    strokeWeight: 20,
    map: map
  });
  
  new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

**Edit:**

You mentioned in your comment you need the stroke to be fixed at a given distance from the center line.

You could still use that technique I think, as you can calculate the size in meters of a map pixel, based on the latitude and the zoom level, and as the size of the stroke is also in pixels, you should be able to recalculate the stroke each time you zoom-in/out. It won't be 100% precise since the stroke width must be an integer, but it should work.

It *should* work if the various Polyline points are more or less on the same latitude, because the resolution of a map with the Mercator projection is dependent on the latitude. So, for example if you have a big Polyline crossing from -70 to +70 latitude, it won't be accurate all the way.

This is the formula you can use to compute the size of 1 map pixel. You would need to replace `map.getCenter().lat()` by your Polyline center point.

```
// Calculate the width of 1 map pixel in meters
let scale = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(map.getCenter().lat() * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
```

Unfortunately, there is an issue with this approach. Although it's undocumented, **a Polyline stroke width can't be bigger than 32px**.

```js
var map;
var polyBounds;
var polyStroke;
var polyWidth = 50; // Width in meters

function initialize() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 20,
      lng: 0
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [{
      lat: 20,
      lng: -0.5
    },
    {
      lat: 20,
      lng: 0.5
    }
  ];

  polyStroke = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: .3,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    map: map
  });

  new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
  });

  polyBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length; i++) {

    polyBounds.extend(flightPlanCoordinates[i]);
  }

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', setStroke);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', setStroke);
}

function setStroke() {

  // Calculate the width of 1 map pixel in meters
  let scale = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(polyBounds.getCenter().lat() * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());

  polyStroke.setOptions({
    strokeWeight: Math.ceil(polyWidth / scale)
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

So unless you find out that these values allow for your use case, this won't be a viable solution...

The solution you were pointed to in the comments ([How to draw a polygon around a polyline in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369363/how-to-draw-a-polygon-around-a-polyline-in-javascript)) is still probably your best option.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  The problem with that though is when you zoom, it doesn't scale the width of the shadow with it... I looked at using svg as well, but that had the same effect.  I need to keep the outline constrained to x metres from the line.

Comment: See my edits. That's a fail, for one simple reason... you can't set a Polyline stroke width that is bigger than 32px :( It might be worth opening a feature request to allow for bigger values...

Comment: FYI, I have created this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119440623) to which you can subscribe in the hope that Google will change something... at some point. But that can take a very long time... :(

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help.. what i've ended up doing is just creating a polyline to show the path... and then using the start and end points, and racking my brain back to high school trigonometry, I have just created an arc at each end of the line with a set radius... this works perfectly, was just a bit more heavy lifting than I would have liked..

Comment: Cool. Feel free to post your solution as a separate answer as it might help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered a much easier way to achieve this using the google maps API.
There are built in functions for getting a bearing of a point based on a start point... 
So I created a function that takes the start and end points of a line, and then creates points around these based on the heading - then create a polygon using those points.

```
var pointCount = 12;
function setLozengePath(startPoint, endPoint) {
  var sp = google.maps.geometry.spherical;
  var heading = sp.computeHeading(startPoint, endPoint);

  var points = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= pointCount; ++i) {
    points.push(sp.computeOffset(endPoint, radius, heading + 90 - i * 15));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= pointCount; ++i) {
    points.push(sp.computeOffset(startPoint, radius, heading - 90 - i * 15));
  }

  return points;
}
```